# Cocos2D parent-child no interaction

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, parent

I have a parent with two children that I want to communicate with each other. For some reason it is not working. Here is what I have:

Parent

```
    GameplayLayer *gameplaylayer = [GameplayLayer node]; // 1
    [self addChild:gameplaylayer z:2 tag:1];

    GameplayLayer2 *gameplaylayer2 = [GameplayLayer2 node]; // 1
    [self addChild:gameplaylayer2 z:20 tag:2];
```

Child

.h

```
#import "GameplayLayer2.h"

@interface GameplayLayer : CCLayer { 
GameplayLayer2* game;
}
```

.m

```
    game = (GameplayLayer2*)[[self parent] getChildByTag:2];
```

But when I try to run a function in `game` like so `[game runfun]` it doesn't run.

Comment: What do you mean it does not run ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check in debugger, that after this call

```
game = (GameplayLayer2*)[[self parent] getChildByTag:2];
```

game instance is not `nil`

Answer (score 1):

If this line...

```
game = (GameplayLayer2*)[[self parent] getChildByTag:2];
```

is being run in `GameplayLayer1`'s init function, then it is being run too early, because you haven't even set up your instance of `GameplayLayer2` by that point.